# Kafka: Is it possible to share data among consumers in a consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have multiple messages (more specifically log messages) in a certain topic which have the same id for a block of messages (these id's keep changing but remain same for a certain block of messages) and I need to find a way to group all the messages with that id or share the data contained in those messages with the same id between all the consumers in a consumer group.
So is there any way I could share data among various consumers in a consumer group?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a sessionization use case to me. Kafka doesn't provide any means of grouping or nesting messages together so you'd have to do that yourself by keeping state in the consumer while processing and wrap the group of messages with some kind of header. Then you could push this to a new topic of wrapped message groups.

A better approach would probably be to make use of an external database or other system with more flexible means of selecting or organizing data based on fields. You can have a look at [this blogpost](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/how-to-do-near-real-time-sessionization-with-spark-streaming-and-apache-hadoop/) for an example using Spark streaming + HBase.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do that.

1. When you publish the message itself, create a message with partition key, so all the messages with same id goes to single partition. then in the consumer side it will always consumed by single consumer.[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example]
2. If you use Spark-streaming in consumer side, you could use sliding window concept to group all the same id messages.[http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations]